# INSERT DELAYED using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can a MySQL clause `INSERT DELAYED` be done using Laravel's Fluent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, at least not with Fluent. Laravel provides you with ways to execute raw queries by way of the `DB::query()` method.

With `DB::query()` you should be able to achieve your desired results.

If for whatever reason it's not working like it should, which mind you for some queries with `DB::query()` they still just don't work, then you'll need to use the raw PDO object. You can get the PDO object via `DB::connection()->pdo`, remember if you're using a custom connection and not the default as defined in your configuration you'll need to pass it in to `DB::connection('connection_name')`

Further information can be found on the Laravel docs: http://laravel.com/docs/database/raw

Comment: Don't forget to use bindings in the second parameter!